# Comment rendre plus élégante la phrase «Son activité « math stack exchange » est une bonne révision »?

Tags: expressions, formulation

Son activité « math stack exchange » est une bonne révision.

Son activité « math stack exchange » est une bonne façon de réviser ses mathématiques.

Devrais-je plutôt écrire: Regarder son activité « math stack exchange » est une bonne révision./Regarder son activité « math stack exchange » est une bonne façon de réviser ses mathématiques.

Bref je cherche une façon plus élégante d’exprimer cette idée.

Merci.

**Autre idée qui me vient à l’esprit: Regarder son activité sur le site Reddit constitue un bon moyen de réviser.

Comment: Il faudrait rendre cela plus spécifique; est-ce l'activité de la personne qui parle ou l'activité de quelqu'un d'autre ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'une activité puisse se qualifier comme "une révision". Participer à X.....

Comment: @LPH. Il s’agit de l’activité de quelqu’un d’autre.

Comment: Réviser activement sur « math stack exchange » est bénéfique. — Les solutions proposées par « math stack exchange » sont pratiques/utiles pour réviser. — … Il y en a d'autres, le contexte (qui est le locuteur, et à qui s'adresse-t-il ?) doit être précisé.

Comment: @Personne. Voici les précisions que vous m’avez demandées: le locuteur, c’est moi, les contributions (activité) viennent d’un autre utilisateur, et je m’adresse en réalité à quiconque désirant réviser ses mathématiques . Ce que je cherche à dire, c’est que les contributions de monsieur Untel sur « Math stack exchange » me sont bénéfiques (et le seraient pour tous), en ce sens qu’elles me permettent de réviser toutes les domaines des mathématiques.

Comment: Dans la phrase, « son » renvoie à la personne qui donne des réponses, « ses » se rapporte à toute personne désirant réviser ses mathématiques, donc ici il s’agit d’une généralisation présupposée à l’ensemble des étudiants en mathématiques.

Comment: Votre dernière proposition est tout à fait cohérente et lisible — Sympa l'hélicoptère {ROTFL} https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_termes_d%27argot_Internet#P,_Q,_R,_S qui a gommé ma réponse précédente :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <s>Le temps qu'il passe</s> sur Math Stack Exchange lui est aussi profitable que de revoir ses cours de mathématiques.

> La consultation des contributions de xxx sur Math Stack Exchange <s>lui</s> est aussi profitable que de réviser ses cours de mathématiques.

> La consultation des contributions de xxx sur Math Stack Exchange est aussi profitable que de réviser ses cours de mathématiques.

> La lecture de ses contributions sur Math Stack Exchange vaut autant qu'une révision de cours de maths.

Comment: Pas pire du tout jiliagre! Je tiens à souligner que ces termes sont employés dans un sens strictement positifs. Pour ce qui est de « Le temps qui passe », est-ce qu’il existe une raison pour laquelle ces termes sont barrés? J’imagine que la barre est là parce que tu as probablement appliqué l’effet barré.

Comment: Oui, bien sûr. J'ai barré *le temps qui passe* après avoir compris que ton *son* ne se référait pas à la même personne que le *ses* final. La première phrase ne rend donc pas l'idée qu'il s'agit des contributions d'une personne en particulier qui sont bénéfiques à celui qui les lit, et pas nécessairement la lecture du site en général. Je peux te demander quelle est ta langue maternelle ?

Answer (score 0):

L’étude des contributions de M. xxxx à math Stack exchange constitue une bonne occasion de réviser nos bases de mathématiques.

Answer (score -1):

- Passer en revue son activité « math Stack Exchange » est/sera un bon exercice de révision.
- Passer en revue son activité « math Stack Exchange » vous fera une bonne révision.
- Passer en revue son activité « math Stack Exchange » résultera pour vous en une bonne révision.

Dans les trois phrases ci-dessus "*La lecture du résultat de*"  ou bien "*Lire le résultat de*" peuvent être utilisés à la place de "*Passer en revue*" et on obtient six phrases de plus qui sont tout aussi valables du point de vue style.

Évidemment, il existe d'autres possibilités sur ce modèle et en cherchant un peu vous pourriez en trouver qui soient peut-être plus expressives.

Comment: Je vous adore LPH! Vos réponses sont toujours d’une qualité remarquable. Je vous lève mon chapeau, mon ami. Je vous encourage à continuer de fournir des réponses aux gens, qui, comme moi, cherchent à mieux s’exprimer et à écrire sans fautes. Il va sans dire que vous avez un don pour l’écriture! Sur cela, je vous remercie et je vous souhaite une excellente journée! :)

Comment: @user25275 Ce sont des compliments très flatteurs que les vôtres; espérons que vous n'aurez pas à les regretter !

Comment: Il y a quelque chose qui *sonne mal*, même si grammaticalement la phrase semble se tenir, *son activité* peut être rattachée à celui qui s'exprime ou au site (même après plusieurs relectures des cas proposés) ? La complexité de lecture, sans doute due à une précision ou un détail manquant, n'en fait pas une phrase élégante, de plus la construction ou le choix des mots ne sont pas "viscéralement" francophone , exit donc l'élégance reconnaissable par l'ignorant en mathématique de la véritable explication mathématique :-)

Comment: @Personne Comme un commentaire précise que l'activité est celle d'une autre personne que celle qui s'exprime je crois que l'on doit assumer que dans le contexte cette autre personne est mentionnée avant la phrase en question (après est aussi possible) et  "_son activité_" ne peut pas être rattachée à la personne qui s'exprime ; cependant, il est possible que cette personne mentionnée soit l'agent supposé de l'action équivalente à une révision ("regarder", lire, …), ce que je n'ai pas bien pris en compte, l'agent selon mes phrases étant une personne quelconque ayant un intérêt similaire. (1/4)

Comment: @Personne Comme je conçois les nécessités de l'expression, si je peux reconnaitre une divergence d'une certaine norme francophone (qui semble se perdre de nos jours) ce n'est pas tellement sur ce plan que je trouve à redire mais sur celui du rapport fondamental entre les mots, rapport que les définitions lexicales impliquent, quelle que soit l'origine de ces définitions, ici de "souche" francophone. Cela semble être une des faiblesses de l'anglais ; ce serait une langue qui ne prendrait pas toujours le temps de passer par B en allant de A à C et donc qui apprendrait à ne pas le prendre. (2/4)

Comment: @Personne Cet état de chose trouve écho dans la remarque en commentaire (activité qualifiée comme révision). Cette "activité" est celle de produire du texte explicatif; on peut donc dire à la place de ce terme "sa production de texte explicatif" est une révision" et on voit immédiatement que ce n'est pas cela qui est une révision selon l'idée de user 25275 mais la consommation de cette production, sa lecture. Néanmoins l'interprétation à la lettre, si so énonciation semble mal exprimée dans la forme, est encore possible : (3/4)

Comment: @Personne "C'est dans la production de texte explicatif qu'il trouve le moyen d'une révision.". En somme l'activité est bien une révision (en termes abscons), mais encore une fois cela n'est pas l'idée voulue. L'idée fondamentale est que c'est quelque chose d'étroitement associé à l'activité qui constitue en fait une révision et on peut considérer cela selon plusieurs angles ("regarder", "lire", "étudier", même "vérifier", et très probablement d'autres encore). (4/4)

Comment: « Passer en revue son activité » signifie littéralement *étudier scrupuleusement l'activité de la personne* ce qui n'est absolument pas ici le sens recherché.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Ce n'est pas le sens de « passer en revue », qui est dans cette phrase utilisé dans son sens figuré : (TLFi)  Au fig. Synon. de _parcourir_ (v. ce mot II B 2 a). [ce mot]  Embrasser par la pensée ou par la réflexion. Synon. passer* en revue, considérer* dans son ensemble.Parcourir un sujet; to browse ♦ parcourir un livre : to glance, skim through a book.

Comment: @LPH: Vous mélangez *à nouveau* plusieurs sens, vous vous trompez de signification. Seul importe de **lire** les réponses ou les questions.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Il n'importe pas selon vous de lire les _références_ dans les questions et les réponses ? Donnez les références de ce que vous avancez et on pourra se faire une idée ; on doit d'abord être d'accord sur les références.

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Je suis d'accord avec vous sur ce point ; c'est une construction   moins qu'idéale du point de vue du rapport entre les sens ; même si l'activité ne résulte qu'en des écritures et donc quelque chose qui est entièrement lisible, ce n'est toujours pas de l'activité dont il s'agit vraiment mais de son résultat. Je vais modifier ça.

Comment: La solution recherchée n'est-elle pas dans la question reformulée ?